# How to get the world coordinates of Tile corner points (unity tilemap)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hexagonal-tiles

Good day!

How to get the world coordinates of Tile corner points (hex point top)? Unity tilemap.

[image]

My code:

```
Vector3Int Vector3IntPoint = new Vector3Int(4,8); // cell
Vector3 worldCenterPos = MyTileMap.CellToWorld(Vector3IntPoint);

worldCenterPos - this is center point?
```

How to calculate the rest of the coordinates of the corners of the tile?

Comment: See if this post regarding finding [point from hexagon center](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#angles) answers a part of the question you have.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need!
And how to get the center point and the top point cell in unity?

Comment: If the pivot of the cell is in the center then `transform.position1 will give the center point. I am not even a beginner in Terrains and stuff, really couldn't help much on that front. For the rest, You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)